# GLSurfaceView.Renderer - Changing the shader program on the fly

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a `RecyclerView` populated with integers that point to which fragment shader I use for the `GLSurfaceView` I connected to a `MediaPlayer`. In my `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, I put the following code:

```
public void onFragmentShaderChanged(int filterPosition)
{
    mFragmentShader = VideoUtils.getFragmentShader(mContext, filterPosition);
    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);
    mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, VideoUtils.getFragmentShader(mContext, filterPosition));
    if (mProgram == 0) {
        return;
    }
    maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
    if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
    }
    maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
    if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
    }

    muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
    if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
    }

    muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
    if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
    }
}
```

This code triggers when I click an element of said `RecyclerView`, reading from the raw file that contains the fragment shader I need depending on the position, then using it to delete the existing program and creating a new one. I'm doing this while the `MediaPlayer` is still running.

When I call this, however, the GLSurfaceView turns green right after the logcat gives me:

> E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Setting `setEGLContextClientVersion(2)` nets me `setRenderer() has already been called in this thread` or something like that.

My questions:

1. Can I change the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`'s program on the fly?
2. If I can't, what about changing the renderer itself, or even the fragment shader of the renderer?
3. If the above isn't feasible, should I re-create the `GLSurfaceView` with a similar renderer just with a different fragment shader?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `onFragmentShaderChanged()` function in my question was called outside the EGL thread.

Thanks to fadden's answer in another question that I have to change the program in the onDrawFrame() function, I watched for the change in the filter position integer variable and created the program with a new fragment shader when the variable really changes on click.